# Android: adding programmatically a TextView is not working

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I have an issue while trying to add a `TextView` to a `RelativeLayout`. My code is this one:

```
        TextView lectureView = new TextView(this);
        LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //lp.setMargins(0,60,0,0);
        lectureView.setTextColor(0xffffff);
        lectureView.setBackgroundColor(0x000080);
        lectureView.setText(lect.getCourse().getName());

        ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mondayRelativeLayout)).addView(lectureView);
        ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mondayRelativeLayout)).invalidate();
```

But actually it seems to be ignored. No `TextView` is added and the code is executed, because I have a log debug statement before those lines and it is printed out correctly. I don't see anything strange in the logs... The only thing is that the `TextView` is not showed.

Does anybody know which is the problem with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: LayoutParams that you are using should be of RelativeLayout if they are not and in which function are you adding your textview

Comment: `LayoutParams` are of `android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. I have put this code in the `onCreate` method of my `Activity`, after the `setContentView` method call.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any problem. Show the relativeLayout xml. In between try setting textSize. Change 0xffffff to `Color.WHITE` and 0x000080 to `Color.BLACK`

Comment: try commenting the last line

Comment: Adding the `setTextSize` solved it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set your layout params for the textview. Do it while you are adding the textview to the RelativeLayout like this

```
    ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mondayRelativeLayout)).addView(lectureView,lp);
```

Comment: What a stupid bug. This actually was the problem. Just adding `lectureView.setLayoutParams(lp);` make it working. Thanks.